# list comprehension

Tags: python, list

У меня есть 2 списка:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 3]
```

Почему такой код не работает:

```
new = [x for x in a if (x in b) else '']
```

Comment: Потому что в такой конструкции слово else не предусмотрено

Comment: `new = [(x if x in b else '') for x in a]`

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [синтаксическим диаграммам](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) `if-else` не является частью comprehension, после for допускается только `if` для фильтра.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 3]

[x if x in b else 0 for x in a]
[1, 0, 3]
```